# Gradle 1.3 is not working for java version 1.8.0_252 on ubuntu 18 lts

Tags: java, gradle, ubuntu-18.04

I have installed Gradle 1.3 for one of my projects following the instructions from this link
[Install Gradle Build Tool on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS](https://www.howtoforge.com/how-to-install-gradle-on-ubuntu-1804/)

below is the sample build.gradle file contents

```
 repositories {
    maven { 
    url = "artifactoryRepoUrl"
    credentials {
        username = 'artifactoryReaderUsername'
        password = 'artifactoryReaderPassword'
    }
   }
    mavenCentral()

   }
   configurations {
   protobuf
   compile.extendsFrom protobuf
   
   mapreducejar
   compile.extendsFrom mapreducejar
   
   pigjar
   compile.extendsFrom pigjar
   }
   sourceSets {
      main {  
        java {  
        srcDir 'src/main/java'  
        }  
        }  
       }
```

for this credentials i have put it in /home/user/.gradle/gradle.properties file

```
    url = "artifactoryRepoUrl()"
    credentials {
        username = 'artifactoryReaderUsername'
        password = 'artifactoryReaderPassword'
    }
```

and we are getting below error

```
   FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

   * Where:
   Build file '/home/USER/Desktop/XXData/data/build.gradle' line: 6

   * What went wrong:
   A problem occurred evaluating root project 'data'.
  > Could not find property 'artifactoryRepoUrl' on 
  org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.repositories.
  DefaultMavenArtifactRepository_Decorated@83298d7.

  * Try:
  Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
  * Exception is:
  org.gradle.api.GradleScriptException: A problem occurred evaluating root project 'data'.
    at 

  org.gradle.groovy.scripts.internal.
  DefaultScriptRunnerFactory$ScriptRunnerImpl.run(DefaultScriptRunnerFactory.java:54)
    at org.gradle.configuration.DefaultScriptPluginFactory$ScriptPluginImpl.
  apply(DefaultScriptPluginFactory.java:116)
  at org.gradle.configuration.BuildScriptProcessor.evaluate(BuildScriptProcessor.java:38)
  at org.gradle.configuration.LifecycleProjectEvaluator
  .evaluate(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:43)
 at org.gradle.api.internal.project.AbstractProject.evaluate(AbstractProject.java:463)
 at org.gradle.api.internal.project.AbstractProject.evaluate(AbstractProject.java:75)
 at 
 org.gradle.configuration.ProjectEvaluationConfigurer
 .execute(ProjectEvaluationConfigurer.java:23)
 at org.gradle.configuration.ProjectEvaluationConfigurer
 .execute(ProjectEvaluationConfigurer.java:21)
 at org.gradle.api.internal.Actions$CompositeAction.execute(Actions.java:67)
 at org.gradle.api.internal.Actions$TransformingActionAdapter.execute(Actions.java:96)
 at org.gradle.api.internal.project.AbstractProject.configure(AbstractProject.java:439)
 at org.gradle.api.internal.project.AbstractProject.allprojects(AbstractProject.java:434)
 at org.gradle.configuration.DefaultBuildConfigurer
 .configure(DefaultBuildConfigurer.java:32)
 at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.
 doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:142)
 at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.
 doBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:113)
 at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:81)
 at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExecuteBuildAction.run(ExecuteBuildAction.java:38)
 at 
 org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessGradleLauncherActionExecuter
 .execute(InProcessGradleLauncherActionExecuter.java:39)
 at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessGradleLauncherActionExecuter
 .execute(InProcessGradleLauncherActionExecuter.java:25)
 at org.gradle.launcher.cli.RunBuildAction.run(RunBuildAction.java:50)
 at org.gradle.api.internal.Actions$RunnableActionAdapter.execute(Actions.java:137)
 at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction
 .execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:201)
 at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction
 .execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:174)
 at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.
 execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:170)
 at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.
   execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:139)
 at 
 org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:33)
 at 
org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:22)
at org.gradle.launcher.Main.doAction(Main.java:48)
at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.EntryPoint.run(EntryPoint.java:45)
at org.gradle.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:39)
at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.runNoExit(ProcessBootstrap.java:50)
at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.run(ProcessBootstrap.java:32)
at org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain.main(GradleMain.java:26)
Caused by: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException:
 Could not find property 'artifactoryRepoUrl' on 
 org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.repositories.
  DefaultMavenArtifactRepository_Decorated@83298d7.
  at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractDynamicObject.
 propertyMissingException(AbstractDynamicObject.java:43)
 at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractDynamicObject.getProperty(AbstractDynamicObject.java:35)
 at org.gradle.api.internal.CompositeDynamicObject.
  getProperty(CompositeDynamicObject.java:94)
 at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.repositories.
 DefaultMavenArtifactRepository_Decorated.getProperty(Unknown Source)
 at build_1jvj20nv5a4acflaplav3fpvm1$_run_closure1_closure2_closure4.
 doCall(/home/USER/Desktop/XXData/data/build.gradle:6)
 at org.gradle.api.internal.ClosureBackedAction.execute(ClosureBackedAction.java:58)
 at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.
  DefaultRepositoryFactory.configure(DefaultRepositoryFactory.java:81)
 at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.
 DefaultRepositoryFactory.maven(DefaultRepositoryFactory.java:73)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.
   DefaultRepositoryHandler.maven(DefaultRepositoryHandler.java:117)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.
  DefaultRepositoryHandler.maven(DefaultRepositoryHandler.java:121)
  at build_1jvj20nv5a4acflaplav3fpvm1$_run_closure1_closure2
 .doCall(/home/USER/Desktop/XXData/data/build.gradle:5)
 at org.gradle.api.internal.ClosureBackedAction.execute(ClosureBackedAction.java:58)
 at org.gradle.util.ConfigureUtil.configure(ConfigureUtil.java:130)
 at org.gradle.util.ConfigureUtil.configure(ConfigureUtil.java:110)
 at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.
 DefaultArtifactRepositoryContainer.configure(DefaultArtifactRepositoryContainer.java:76)
 at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.
  DefaultArtifactRepositoryContainer.configure(DefaultArtifactRepositoryContainer.java:44)
 at org.gradle.api.internal.ClosureBackedAction.execute(ClosureBackedAction.java:50)
 at org.gradle.util.ConfigureUtil.configure(ConfigureUtil.java:130)
 at org.gradle.util.ConfigureUtil.configure(ConfigureUtil.java:91)
 at org.gradle.api.internal.initialization.
 AbstractScriptHandler.repositories(AbstractScriptHandler.java:66)
 at build_1jvj20nv5a4acflaplav3fpvm1$_run_closure1.
 doCall(/home/USER/Desktop/XXData/data/build.gradle:4)
 at org.gradle.api.internal.ClosureBackedAction.execute(ClosureBackedAction.java:58)
 at org.gradle.util.ConfigureUtil.configure(ConfigureUtil.java:130)
 at org.gradle.util.ConfigureUtil.configure(ConfigureUtil.java:91)
 at org.gradle.api.internal.project.AbstractProject.buildscript(AbstractProject.java:888)
 at org.gradle.api.Project$buildscript.call(Unknown Source)
 at org.gradle.api.internal.project.ProjectScript.buildscript(ProjectScript.groovy:42)
 at org.gradle.api.Script$buildscript.callCurrent(Unknown Source)
 at build_1jvj20nv5a4acflaplav3fpvm1.run(/home/USER/Desktop/XXData/data/build.gradle:1)
 at org.gradle.groovy.scripts.internal.
 DefaultScriptRunnerFactory$ScriptRunnerImpl.run(DefaultScriptRunnerFactory.java:52)
 ... 32 more


 BUILD FAILED

  Total time: 2.489 secs
```

Me and my colleague trying to figure out this error from last 24hrs and we are not able to find out the issue and can someone help us here.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Gradle 1.3 was released on Nov 20, 2012... that's a *long* time ago. If this is a new project, you might look into using a more recent version of Gradle.

Comment: Sounds like Gradle is complaining that "artifactoryRepoUrl()" is not defined. Is it supposed to be a method that returns the URL of your Artifactory repository?

Comment: It's an old project and so have to deal with it till the migration happens

Comment: @dnault this is variable, not a function, I will edit now and even after directly put the value instead of gradle.properties file, its still the same error